# eclipse - how to open a text-like file type if it's registered with another application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I like using Eclipse to open up certain text-based files that are huge - 140MB - because unlike `notepad++`, Eclipse can open larger files.

With `notepad++`, I could drag-drop a file into an open instance and it'd open it. With Eclipse, whether I do **File>Open file** or drag-drop, it still pops-open the Windows 10 **Please select an application to open the file-type**

**QUESTION**
How can I force Eclipse to open them even if they are registered to be opened by another application?

Comment: I believe if you use right click > Open-Width you can pick "Text-Editor" to use eclipse's built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the editor to open files in with a right click.

Text Editor is eclipse, System Editor is whatever your OS chooses.

I believe default editor is what eclipse chooses based on the extension (Text editor vs. System Editor)

[image]

Comment: What about if the file to open is not imported into the project?

Comment: @Adrian Files which are not in the workspace are very much second class citizens in Eclipse and don't get as much support.